# Primary expression error when defining a vector with ternary operator

Tags: c++

I have a simple code where I try to define a vector as one of two initializer lists using a ternary operator:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> const vec = true ? {3,4} : {5};
    for (int const item : vec) {
        cout << item << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But then I see the below primary-expression error:

```
tmp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tmp.cpp:7:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
     std::vector<int> const vec = true ? {3,4} : {5};
                                         ^
tmp.cpp:7:41: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘{’ token
tmp.cpp:7:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
tmp.cpp:7:47: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘:’ token
     std::vector<int> const vec = true ? {3,4} : {5};
```

I couldn't find anything relevant in either ternary operator or initializer list initialization. What am I missing here?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Why are you using the ternary expression for this? Why can't you use plain assignment within a proper `if ... else ...`?

Comment: Try `auto const vec = true ? std::vector<int>{3,4} : std::vector<int>{5};`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was hoping for a one-liner code, didn't expect that line to throw up so many errors. Now I'm curious over what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't have braces in that context.
If you look at [cppreference on list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), you see that the case inside a ternary operator isn't defined. So it can't be parsed correctly and you get the error you have.

You'd have to use something like this :

```
std::vector<int> const vec{(true ? std::vector<int>{3, 4} : std::vector<int>{5})};
```

Which basically expands to:

```
  if (true) {
    vec = std::vector<int>{3, 4};
  } else {
    vec = std::vector<int> { 5 }
  };
```